# patgen: what do these values mean?

Tags: hyphenation, patgen

What do `hyph_start`, `hyph_finish`, `pat_start`, `pat_finish`, good weight, bad weight and threshold asked by `patgen` mean?

Answer (score 4):

These are extra integer values required to tune the hyphenation generation.
They are documented if you use `man patgen` or `info patgen`:

```
       After  reading the translate_file and any previously-generated pat‐
       terns from pattern_file, patgen requests input from the user's ter‐
       minal.

       First  the integer values of hyph_start and hyph_finish, the lowest
       and highest hyphenation level for which patterns are to  be  gener‐
       ated. The value of hyph_start should be larger than any hyphenation
       level already present in pattern_file.

       Then, for each hyphenation level, the integer values  of  pat_start
       and  pat_finish, the smallest and largest pattern length to be ana‐
       lyzed, as well as good  weight,  bad  weight,  and  threshold,  the
       weights  for good and bad hyphens and a weight threshold for useful
       patterns.

       Finally the decision (`y' or `Y' vs. anything else) whether or  not
       to produce a hyphenated word list.
```

Comment: What is a hyphenation level?

Comment: @antonio It's over 20 years since I last ran patgen, why are you running it, it is one way of generating hyphenation patterns but highly specialised and almost no one should ever need to use it.

Comment: I need a syllabificated dictionary. I could use the hyphenation dictionary of OpenOffice to generate it, but it seems to be edited by hand, without using pagten and is not accurate. I want to generate my own hyphenation dictionary in order to generate a syllabificated dictionary.

Comment: I got your question re-opened as I thought it reasonable but I have forgotten anything I knew about patgen, but now it's open there may be others who have used it more recently. main doc is Liang's thesis http://tug.org/docs/liang/liang-thesis.pdf

Comment: I have already read all this.

Comment: @antonio I thought you might have, but it might help others who are wondering what patgen is and it was the best I could offer at 2 in the morning:-)